# Autoconf/Automake generates an empty make file

Tags: makefile, autoconf

I'm trying to create a very simple build script using the autoconf/automake tool chain (mostly as a learning exercise.)

Most examples seem to indicate that you need a separate `Makefile.am` in every source directory, and that the `Makefile.am` file in the project root should include a `SUBDIRS` directive which tells autoconf where to look for additional Makefiles.

I thought it might be possible, for a very simple project, to have a single `Makefile.am` in the project root directory.  However, when I try to do this, and run the generated `configure` script - it creates a single Makefile in the project root which is empty (0 bytes.)

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

So, my directory structure is extremely simple:

```
MyProject
---src
------myproject.cpp
---Makefile.am
---configure.ac
```

The `configure.ac` file is minimal:

```
AC_INIT(myproject, 1.0)
AC_MSG_NOTICE([My Project])
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG(C++)
AC_CHECK_HEADERS(iostream)
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR(src/myproject.cpp)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(MyProject, 1.0)
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

And the `Makefile.am` is also very simple:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = myproject
myproject_SOURCES = src/myproject.cpp
myproject_CPPFLAGS = --std=c++11
```

I run:

```
autoconf configure.ac > configure
```

When I run the configure script, there are no errors.

Then I see it generated a `Makefile` in the project root directory:

```
 # ls -lh | grep Make
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  8 16:13 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   98 Nov  8 15:53 Makefile.am
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov  8 15:00 Makefile.in
```

And you can see, the Makefile it generated is completely empty.

So I'm obviously misunderstanding something fundamental about how autoconf/automake is supposed to work.  What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Did you run `automake`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - where automake would generate empty Makefiles. I don't know why it happened, but I fixed it by deleting all the files generated by autoconf, e.g. Makefile.in (the zero-byte Makefile.in is definitely bad).

You can also try `autoreconf -if`

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting, I have tried to reproduce your case and I got different, albeit expected results.

- The `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` invocation is [obsolete](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Public-Macros.html), you should write `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])`. The `foreign` tells automake not to complain about missing `README`, `ChangeLog`, etc.
- You have your `Makefile.am` in a different folder than source files. Although it is OK, the new automake should complain that it is a forward-incompatibility, I got this on the output (automake 1.15):

  ```
  Makefile.am:2: warning: source file 'src/myproject.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
  Makefile.am:2: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
  automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
  automake: At least a source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
  automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
  ...
  ```

  Those are just warnings though.
- Anyway, instead of running just `autoconf`, I have ran `autoreconf -i` (or `-i -f` to be sure --- the `-f` option overwrites all files those tool generate). Autoreconf runs `autoconf`, `automake` and other tools in the right order for you.
- After `autoreconf` finished, I got a configure script that worked as expected and after running it, I got a correct Makefile, too.